# SOQL required for a SQL

Tags: soql, lookup, sql, childrelationship

Cam someone please convert the below SQL query to SOQL?

[image]

SQL:

> Select id, Name, product_code, 
>   (select product_code from product b where b.parent_id=a. id) as parent_code 
>   from product a

How to get these results through in salesforce/SOQL?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? It'll be more valuable for you if you work through this instead of someone just giving you the answer outright.

Comment: I am new to SOQL, I tried and finally posted here. You can simply  Ignore !!!

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to do a **[`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join)**.

First step is to find the child relationship name. If you have a custom lookup, it's going to end in `__r` and it's usually plural. So for example if it were `Products__r`, you would do:

```
SELECT (SELECT Product_Code__c FROM Products__r) FROM Parent_Object__c
```

Comment: your query returns  product code of a child record. Parent 1|  **ch1** , I want the code for parent i.e Child1 | **pr1**